# Can't connect to MongoLab database with URI. The shell works though

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mlab

I'm really not sure why I can't connect to my mongodb database from nodejs, using a URI connection string.

I am however able to connect using the mongo shell. Proof:

[image]

Here is my connection code:

```
MongoClient.connect("mongodb://myusername:mypassword@ds043694.mongolab.com:43694/node-mongo-blog", {
    db: {
        w:1,
        native_parser:false
    },
    server: {
        poolSize:5,
        socketoptions: {connectTimeoutMS: 500},
        auto_reconect: true
    },
    replSet: {},
    mongos: {}
}, connectionCallback);
```

Yes I can guarantee I spelt the login correctly, because I tried a hundred times. I can also guarantee that the code is properly connecting, because it works with my localhost db. I also tried creating other users, however they all can't connect via URI. I am using mongodb 4.07.

The error received is:

```
{ [MongoError: auth failed] name: 'MongoError', ok: 0, errmsg: 'auth failed', code: 18 }
```

Can someone explain this, because I have no idea why it isn't working.

Comment: Oh yeah, I also tried editing the `connectTimeoutMS` to an outrageously high number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue was that I recently updated mongodb to 3.07, however never considered the fact that the mongodb-native-driver would not be compatible with the update.

MongoLab posted a message stating:

`If you cannot authenticate to a deployment running MongoDB 3.0, ensure that you are using a 3.0-compatible driver.`

They then sent me to this link: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/3.0-compatibility/#driver-compatibility-changes

I looked up nodeJS, and found that I need something >=v.1.4.29. Now that it is updated everything works.